# How to make Yelp's search by features functionality

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make Yelps search by features functionality. So I have businesses that can have many features like: `Has TV`, `Dogs Allowed`, `Wi-Fi` and so on.

I made these tables:

```
------------
|businesses|
|----------|
|id        |
|name      |
------------

------------------
|business_feature|
------------------
|business_id     |
|feature_id      |
------------------

-----------------
|features       |
-----------------
|id             |
|name           |
-----------------
```

Imagine I would like to find a restauran(business) where I could go with my dog that has Wi-Fi and TV. So I need to display businesses that has all these features: `Has TV(id:1)`, `Dogs Allowed(id:6)`, `Wi-Fi(id:11)` and if it doesnt have any of them dont include it in the result.

I have tried the following SQL:

```
SELECT businesses.* FROM businesses 
JOIN business_feature ON businesses.id = business_feature.business_id 
JOIN features ON business_feature.feature_id = feature.id
WHERE feature.id IN (1,6,11)
```

It is working but It shows businesses that has any of those features. But I need businesses that has all of them, not one. Please help

Comment: `GROUP BY b.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` - this assumes that relations are unique, but you can use `COUNT (DISTINCT(...))` if (for some crazy reason) they're not!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! Can you make an answer

Comment: It's a faq, so no